# How do I show decimal inventory amount on the frontend?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I'm coding a website for a fabric shop that sells by the yard. They sell in decimal quanities which I have figured out how to enable. However in the front end (list and view) it doesn't show the decimal amount on the end. For instance, if there is 24.75 yds in stock, it displays that there are 24 yds in stock.

What would I need to do to fix that?
Thanks!

```
<?php $qty = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty(); echo $qty; ?>
```

Comment: how are you displaying the stock amount on the product display page? some code would be useful

Comment: I edited my original post to add the code. see above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you remove the (int) casting and try that?

```
<?php 
    $qty = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty(); 
    echo number_format((float) $qty, 2, '.', ''); 
?>
```

Comment: That's better, but now it shows 4 decimal places. For instance 24.7500. Is there anyway to limit it to two?